# Google Play valid privacy policy

Tags: android

Bom Dia,

Recebi um e-mail da Google a referir que a minha app deveria ter uma valid privacy policy, no entanto não sei bem como cria-la.

Alguém já passou por esta necessidade que me possa ajudar e explicar como posso resolver isto?

Atenciosamente
Nuno Santos

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim ó ->

pode pegar esse exemplo aqui ó: https://media.termsfeed.com/pdf/privacy-policy-template.pdf, traduza para a(s) linguagem(s) que vc implementou no aplicativo e põe tudo num arquivo .html e publica esse arquivo no seu dominio.

Feito isso, vai no developer console em "detalhes do aplicativo", bem em baixo, tem "Politica de Privacidade", no campo "url" voce poe a url apontando para o arquivo que vc criou no passo assima, algo tipo: http://seudominio.com/apps/suaprivacypolicy.html.

No meu caso, eu tenho varios apps, todos eles em mais de uma lingua, dai eu criei a pagina em php e passo o app pela url e mostro conforme o nome informado na url, tipo **http...myprivpol.php?app=App que Quero ostrar"**, mesmo porque pra mim, em todos os apps, a minha privacy policy é generica.
Também implementei um mecanismo jquery na pagina que criei para abrir na lingua do cara.

é isso.